# Word for something sad and funny at the same time

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word for conflicting emotions that are felt at the same time? For example, *loneliness*, *sadness*, *happiness*, being *content* but also feeling as if something isn't right?

To sum up: What's a word for something that is sad and funny at the same time?

Comment: Does it need to be one word?  I've heard the phrase *"that is both depressing and hilarious"* on more than one occasion.

Comment: funny and sad at the same time? A clown?

Comment: It doesn't quite fit OP's request for "a word", but "tears of a clown" is certainly a standard phrase used in some contexts.

Comment: @nick *Funny*, man, not *scary*. :P

Comment: "English" *runs away*

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The word you want is *[tragicomedy](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tragicomedy?q=tragicomedy)* (noun) or *tragicomic* (adjective).

Comment: Although [tragicomic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tragicomic) is likely the form that the OP is looking for.

Comment: This is close, but not unequivocal. *Sad* and *tragic* share some characteristics but are not really synonyms. The OP may decide if it works for him well enough.

Answer (score 34):

I think [*bittersweet*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bittersweet) is the best word to describe this feeling.

> both pleasant and painful or regretful: *a bittersweet memory.*

It's also less "modern" sounding than *tragicomic* and so would come across as more sincere.

Comment: *Bittersweet* doesn't imply *funny*, though.

Comment: I think "tragic" is closer to "sad" than "sweet" is to "funny," swinging the count in favor of *tragicomic* over *bittersweet* in this example.

Comment: I agree *bittersweet* is certainly more common than *tragicomic* in general parlance, but imho it's more akin to *poignant* - the "sweet" part generally implies overwhelming joy, rather than just something amusing/funny.

Comment: I would still prefer two words like *bittersweet laughter* rather than the word *tragicomic.*

Answer (score 7):

I like the word "wry," although it has a large context.

Comment: Yes, I like "wry" for a lot of contexts where sadness and humour are being juxtaposed.

Answer (score 5):

A general word for having simultaneous, contradictory emotions is *[ambivalent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambivalent)*.

Comment: According to that definition, yes, you're right.
It would surprise me if that was a common usage, though. I've *never* heard it used that way. It's always been a lack of concern about the state of something to me.
Being ambivalent about same-sex marriage to me doesn't mean your very enthusiastic about it, while also hating the idea.

Comment: @DefenestrationDay Yeah, it normally connotes "simultaneous attraction toward and repulsion from" something or somebody [MW] -- but _tragicomic_ had already been submitted...

Answer (score 3):

Per other answers, *tragicomic* fits the bill - but its use is largely restricted to litcrit contexts.

In common parlance, [pathos](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pathos) and the related *pathetic* are often used ironically, of something that in principle should arouse pity, but in fact is treated with wry humour. Not so common in speech is [bathos](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/bathosterm.htm), which often signifies a sudden transition from genuine pathos to ludicrous levity.

Comment: But "pathetic" has largely taken on the meaning of "deserving contempt" rather than the old meaning of "deserving pity". If you say, "Bob is really pathetic" few people would reply, "Yes, I feel sorry for him, too". More likely they would say "Yes, he's a real jerk, isn't he?" or "No, I think he's a nice guy."

Comment: @Jay: Yes, I quite agree. *Pathetic* has been enthusiastically taken up for all sorts of contexts including various shades of "contemptible", including those where one is effectively *laughing at the person thus described* (not *laughing* **with**).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the more common choice for what you're describing is *ironic*, but, admittedly, doesn't necessarily capture the presence of the two elements you cite. Nor does it seem likely that any one particular word has been established that's capable of accomplishing that feat. Is that what you're looking for or will a neologism do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Gallows Humor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallows_humor) isn't a perfect fit, but in general the *Doom & Gloom* of the style of humor could be considered to be fairly synonymous with *sadness*, and of course *humor* is basically a perfect fit for the *funny* half of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

Melancholy means for something to be both sad and happy at the same time. It has a nice, find feeling but still makes you sad

Answer (score 0):

- Dark (as in dark comedy)
- Lol-worthy (when something seems only sad, but you need to strike a funny abstract note without making a joke)

Comment: I have seen *lolsob*.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for a word describing one's state of mind and mood, and also conflicting emotions, perhaps, the word *broody* would help, as its first meaning is moody, meditative, introspective:

> **broody**, adjective *broodier, broodiest*
>
> 1. moody; meditative; introspective
> 2. (of poultry) wishing to sit on or hatch eggs
> 3. (informal) (of a woman) wishing to have a baby of her own

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/broody

Answer (score -1):

**satire**:

> **satire** ˈsaˌtī(ə)r/ *noun* The use of humor, irony, exaggeration, or ridicule to expose and criticize people's stupidity or vices, particularly in the context of contemporary politics and other topical issues.

*Source: [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/satire).*

Synonyms:

> mockery, ridicule, derision, scorn, caricature, irony, sarcasm

*Source: [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english-thesaurus/satire).*

That was what I was looking for when I came upon this thread.

Comment: I have added links to two separate pages of Oxford Dictionaries, which seem to have been the source of the quoted language above. Please identify the sources of all quoted language included in future questions and answers you post on English Language & Usage.