# What is the term for happy and anxious at the same time?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example if somebody becomes president they are surely feeling happy, but at the same time probably anxious. Is there one word for that?

Comment: Also related: [Word for something sad and funny at the same time.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55839/)

Comment: I've certainly heard/read "hanxious".

Comment: @HotLicks http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Hanxious

Comment: This question looks for a specific case , so it can't be said to be duplicate of the linked question. 'Ambivalent' certainly does not fit here

Comment: I agree with R.S., the suggested duplicate does not answer this question. As far as the specific case in question, "eager" could be considered a happy/positive type of anxiousness.

Comment: But eager is completely different thing,is it not?@vanderpn